# Finding frequencies of three-character sequences in a string

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am having trouble with finding sets of thre letters in a string.
My current code is:

```
if [ -e  $1 ]
then
    echo File Exists
    grep -E -o -c \("[acgt][acgt][acgt]"\) $1
else
    echo File doesnt Exist
fi
```

How do I show the amount of times an occurrence happens in a string?
For example, my string would contain

```
aacgtttgtaaccagaactgt
aac 3
tgt 2
```

etc.

Comment: This is coursework from [CSCI132 at Hunter College, CUNY, set by Professor Stewart Weiss](http://www.compsci.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/course_materials/csci132/csci132_f10.php). Specifically, it is course assignment 4, usually due in the middle of the Michaelmas Term. Submitting someone else’s work as your own is explicitly listed as an example of academic dishonesty in CUNY's academic integrity policy. There are similar examples in Hunter College's academic integrity policy. Sanctions for academic dishonesty at CUNY range from a failing grade for the course to expulsion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tail`, `fold`, `grep`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
for i in {1..3}; do tail -c +"$i" infile; done | fold -w 3 | grep -Evx '.{,2}' |
    sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

resulting in

```
      3 aac
      2 tgt
      1 ttt
      1 ttg
      1 taa
      1 gtt
      1 gta
      1 gaa
      1 ctg
      1 cgt
      1 cca
      1 cag
      1 aga
      1 act
      1 acg
      1 acc
```

Here is how this works:

- `tail -c +"$i" infile` prints the contents of `infile` starting at the offset corresponding to the value of `$i`, so the output of the for loop is

  ```
  aacgtttgtaaccagaactgt
  acgtttgtaaccagaactgt
  cgtttgtaaccagaactgt
  ```

The intermediate output for the rest is shown at the end, with stages numbered from left to right corresponding to the numbered list items:

1. `fold -w 3` makes lines of three characters each.
2. `grep -Evx '.{,2}'` removes (`-v`) lines where the complete line (`-x`) matches two or fewer characters (`.{,2}`). The `-E` option allows us to not escape the curly braces, but `grep -vx '.\{,2\}'` would work just as well.
3. `sort` sorts the output alphabetically (`uniq` requires sorted input).
4. `uniq -c` counts occurrences of identical lines.
5. `sort -nr` sorts by occurrences, descending.

   ```
    1.      2.      3.              4.              5.
   ---------------------------------------------------
   aac     aac     aac           3 aac           3 aac
   gtt     gtt     aac           1 acc           2 tgt
   tgt     tgt     aac           1 acg           1 ttt
   aac     aac     acc           1 act           1 ttg
   cag     cag     acg           1 aga           1 taa
   aac     aac     act           1 cag           1 gtt
   tgt     tgt     aga           1 cca           1 gta
   acg     acg     cag           1 cgt           1 gaa
   ttt     ttt     cca           1 ctg           1 ctg
   gta     gta     cgt           1 gaa           1 cgt
   acc     acc     ctg           1 gta           1 cca
   aga     aga     gaa           1 gtt           1 cag
   act     act     gta           1 taa           1 aga
   gt      cgt     gtt           2 tgt           1 act
   cgt     ttg     taa           1 ttg           1 acg
   ttg     taa     tgt           1 ttt           1 acc
   taa     cca     tgt
   cca     gaa     ttg
   gaa     ctg     ttt
   ctg
   t
   ```

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm sorry i didn't clearly state my problem. Instead of finding out all the sequences of 3 letters, i want to find out the sequences that are continuosly happening. For example, my string is aacgtttgtaaccagaactgt and the whole output should be 3 aac 2 tgt 1 cag 1 gtt. thanks for the help again

Comment: instead of grep grep -Evx '.{,2}'  should I do grep -Evx '\([acgt][acgt][acgt]\)*'   Thanks for the help again

Comment: @MohammadKhalid I don't quite understand "continuously happening". Do you want to cut your string into groups of three each and then get the frequency count of each group? So if your string were `aacgtt`, you'd only want `aac` and `gtt`, but not `acg` and `cgt`?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I mean. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to match each three-character permutation of the characters `{acgt}{acgt}{acgt}` against each substring within `aacgtttgtaaccagaactgt`. Bash can do that quite simply with *brace expansion* alone and using *string indexes* and checking each 3-character substring within the test string, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

str=aacgtttgtaaccagaactgt    ## string
len=${#str}                  ## length

while read -r pat; do        ## read each permutation from process substitution

    patlen=${#pat}           ## get the pattern length
    endex=$((len-patlen+1))  ## indexes to check (inclusive)
    declare -i ct=0          ## counter for matches

    ## check each character in $str
    for ((i = 0; i < endex; i++)); do
        ## test each $patlen substring against pattern, increment ct
        test "${str:$i:$patlen}" = "$pat" && ((ct++))
    done

    printf "%s  %d\n" "$pat" $ct  ## output results

done < <(printf "%s\n" {a,c,g,t}{a,c,g,t}{a,c,g,t})
```

**note:** the permutations are created by `printf` and the brace expansion

```
printf "%s\n" {a,c,g,t}{a,c,g,t}{a,c,g,t}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash acgtpermcount.sh
aaa  0
aac  3
aag  0
aat  0
aca  0
acc  1
acg  1
act  1
aga  1
agc  0
agg  0
agt  0
ata  0
atc  0
atg  0
att  0
caa  0
cac  0
cag  1
cat  0
cca  1
ccc  0
ccg  0
cct  0
cga  0
cgc  0
cgg  0
cgt  1
cta  0
ctc  0
ctg  1
ctt  0
gaa  1
gac  0
gag  0
gat  0
gca  0
gcc  0
gcg  0
gct  0
gga  0
ggc  0
ggg  0
ggt  0
gta  1
gtc  0
gtg  0
gtt  1
taa  1
tac  0
tag  0
tat  0
tca  0
tcc  0
tcg  0
tct  0
tga  0
tgc  0
tgg  0
tgt  2
tta  0
ttc  0
ttg  1
ttt  1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**note:** if you have a 100,000,000 character test string, you are probably going to want a tool faster than bash to process it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more simple solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
str='aacgtttgtaaccagaactgt'
for a in a c g t; do
    for e in a c g t; do
        for i in a c g t; do
            echo "${a}${e}${i} $(echo "$str" | grep -o "${a}${e}${i}" | wc -l)" | grep -vP '0$'
        done
    done
done
```